# How to draw an X or an O in a tic-tac-toe game using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Background: doing a tic-tac-toe game using HTML, CSS and Jquery. Also using Bootstrap's CSS library and jQuery's JavaScript library. Used the Bootstrap's grid system to create the empty tic-tac-toe game board.

Question on this step: Draw an X or an O when a user clicks one of the squares on the board.

The actual question: So far I only found this possible solution:
jQuery animate() Method. Would this be one way to go? Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You could use images. One for X and another for O. Pretty simple to put img tags in the grid and set the src property to x.png or o.png - Or just put divs in the grid blocks and set add text to them in a large font size.

Comment: I haven't used Bootstrap but I guess the grid system consists of multiple divisions so just use jQuery's append function to append an X or an O to the clicked division and apply some CSS style to it. `$('yourdivision').append('X');`

Comment: just toggle classes ... simplest way